# How to access the last n elements of a string in c?

Tags: c, c-strings, strlen

So I was making a code and I got stuck because I was unable to figure out how to access the the last n elements of a string. I tried using the string.h library but it did not work as there is no such function that can access the last elements of a string. Could anyone help me please ?

Comment: Well, `strlen()` will give you the length. You can then subtract from that as needed.

Comment: There's no "built-in API".  [strlen()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) tells you how many characters are in the string.  The "last element" is `strlen()-1`.  For there... you'll probably just need to write a loop.

Comment: Find out the length of a string, ten subtract `n`. Don't forget to test if the length is at least `n` and adjust your decision accordingly if not.

Comment: You could write a function to do this very easily. If the string length is `x` then you want to index the string at `x - n - 1` (the -1 is to acomodate for zero-indexing). Then just read from that index up until the end of the string.

Comment: Could be interresting to know what kind of application that would need the last N characters of a string

Comment: @4386427 "what kind of application that would need the last N characters " --> akin to Excel `RIGHT()`.

Comment: C doesn't have any `substr` functions, because any such function would want to return a new string, which is eternally problematic in C, because of allocation issues, and the way strings are not first-class types.  So you're left with pointer arithmetic, which works quite well most of the time, but isn't really worth relegating to a library function, so you just end up doing it yourself, "by hand", all the time.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *lastN(const char *str, size_t n)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    return (char *)str + len - n;
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("`%s`\n", lastN("1234567890", 4));
}
```

Comment: and remember to check that `len >= n`

Comment: @4386427 let's leave something for OP as well

Comment: Given the complexicity of the question. I doubt that can be left to OP without mentioning it at all

Comment: Additionally, as it is this is a "code only" answer and could likely be improved with a bit of context, detail, and warning to the user.

Answer (score 2):

The header `<string.h>` contains function `strlen` that returns the length of a passed string. The function is declared like

```
    size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

Strictly speaking the last character of a string is its terminating zero character '\0'. But it seems by the last n characters of a string you mean n characters before the terminating zero.

To be able to get a pointer to the last n characters of a string the string should have at least n characters.

You could write a function the following way. If the passed string contains less than n characters then the function returns a pointer to the string itself.

```
char * last_n( const char *s, size_t n )
{
    size_t length = strlen( s );

    return ( char * )( length < n ? s : s + length - n );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * last_n( const char *s, size_t n )
{
    size_t length = strlen( s );

    return ( char * )( length < n ? s : s + length - n );
} 

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Hello world!";
    
    char *p = last_n( s, 6 );
    
    puts( p );
    
    for ( char *current = p; *current != '\0'; ++current )
    {
        *current = toupper( ( unsigned char )*current );
        putchar( *current );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
world!
WORLD!
```

If you need to obtain the index where the last n characters of a string start you can write for example

```
char *p = last_n( s, n );
size_t pos = p - s;
```

Or just

```
size_t pos = last_n( s, n ) - s;
```

Answer (score -1):

In C, strings are just `char` arrays. And arrays are `0`-indexed. This means that the first element has an index of `0`, the second element has an index of `1`, ..., and the last element has an index of `n-1`, assuming `n` is the length of the string (or the `char` array).

```c
char *string = "Hello";
int len = strlen(string);
printf("%c", string[len-1]); // prints the last character 'o'
```

To access the last `n` elements, you can calculate the index from which the last sequence of `n` characters start: `i = len - n`:

```c
// Returns the index of the first element of the last n elements
int last_n(char *string, int n)
{
    return strlen(string) - n;
}
```

Comment: This is close to the right idea, but 1) it does not provide a solution for accessing the *last `n` elements* of the string and 2) does not implement the solution in the form of a function as the OP requested.

Comment: `size` as wrong type

Comment: `printf("%s", string[size-1]);` it is undefined behaviour

Comment: @4386427 I have edited the code. Thank you.

Comment: @h0r53 I've added a function

Comment: @0___________ That was a typo. It's actually `%c`.

Comment: I'm not sure the `last_n` function as defined is super useful. Either returning a substring or a new string is more desirable, although returning a new string would require the caller to `free` the allocated memory and perhaps that's too complex for the OP's scenario.